# Pytest fixtures not able to use each other in conftest.py

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fastapi

I am writing tests for a simple tweet posting API using FastAPI and pytest.
I decided to use pytest fixtures with yield so that I have a "setup" step and a "teardown" step before and after each test.

So if I want to test the `create_tweet` endpoint, I must use a `temp_user` fixture that creates a user before running the `test_create_tweet`, and when the test is finished, the fixture resumes on where it left of (after the `yield`) to delete the user.

Like this:

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(params=users, name="user", scope="session")
def temp_user(request):
    # Setup
    token = user_setup(user:=request.param)
    client.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer %s" % token

    yield user

    # Teardown:
    response = client.delete("/users/")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, "User deletion failed!"
```

```
# tests.py

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("user")
def test_create_tweet(tweet):
    res = client.post("tweets/", json=tweet)
    pytest.last_created_tweet_id = TweetReturn(**res.json()).id
    assert res.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

Taking this one step further, when I want to test the `get`*`tweet`*`details` endpoint, apart from creating a temporary user I need to also create some tweets before running the test. So I created another fixture inside my **conftest.py** file:

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("user")
@pytest.fixture(params=tweets, name="tweet", scope="session")
def temp_tweet(request):
    tweet = request.param
    response = client.post("tweets/", json=tweet)
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED  # ERROR OCCURS HERE: 401 NOT AUTHENTICATED (BECAUSE FIXTURE "USERS" WAS SKIPPED UNEXPECTEDLY)

    tweet = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    yield tweet

    response = client.delete(f"tweets/{tweet['id']}")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
```

This new fixture (temp tweet) needs to be able to **run first temp users as a dependency and then call its' contents**, because an authorized user is needed to create a tweet.

But as it seems, when I am running the following test, **the temp_tweet is only executed without the temp user**, with the result of getting a 401 (not authorized) error.

```
def test_get_tweet_details(tweet): 
    res = client.get(f"tweets/{tweet['id']}")
    assert res.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Why is this happening? What could I do to solve this?

I have tried changing the scope of the fixtures in case that played a role.
I tried calling temp tweet as a dependency of temp user and they still couldn't see each other.
After some experimentation I noticed that tests see the fixtures but the problem occurs when one fixture has to call the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!** Running a very simple pytest suite (one file) made what was the issue obvious.

**TL;DR:** *The problem was that a fixture can't call another one using the* `@pytest.mark.usefixtures(<other_fixture_name>)`!

To find the problem I created a file that does the same thing I described in my post but in a more simple form:

```
# test.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def f():
    print("f called")
    return 1


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("f")  # <- SILENT ERROR (NOT WORKING)
@pytest.fixture
def g():
    print("g called")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("g")
def test_foo():
    assert True
```

Running `pytest -sv test.py` would print in the standard output this:

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

conftest.py::test_foo g called
PASSED
```

But if I changed the `g()` fixture to call `f()` from the parameter declaration i.e.

```
# test.py
@pytest.fixture
def g(f):
    print("g called")
```

rerunning `pytest -sv test.py`, the output would show that `f()` was run before `g()` as expected:

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

conftest.py::test_foo f called
g called
PASSED
```